# How to make a Git repository behave like a REST endpoint

Tags: rest, authentication, github, oauth-2.0

Is there a way to make a Git repository behave like a REST endpoint such that I can change the code hosted on GitHub to change based on a [PUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) request?

Example:

In the repository below I want some external REST end point URL to change the value from `http://localhost:8080/app/` to some new value like `http://example.com` using a [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) action.

```
https://github.com/TechieTester/gatling-
fundamentals/blob/master/src/gatling/scala/baseConfig/BaseSimulation.scala
```

I need to change the code I have on GitHub using a REST endpoint POST action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not a way to make your Git repository on GitHub act as a REST API endpoint. This would be using GitHub pages and that does not allow server-side code. Per their documentation:

> GitHub Pages is a static site hosting service and doesn't support
> server-side code such as, PHP, Ruby, or Python.

You can setup a REST API that makes updates to your GitHub repository. An example project to look at is Staticman comments engine for static sites: https://github.com/eduardoboucas/staticman